# how do i adjust this application window while running

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, simulator

After running

[image]

Before running(in xcode storyboard)

[image]

I am getting black screen at the top and bottom layer of the application while running. I don't want that screen. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshots. please take a look.

Comment: Add Launch.Storyboard or splash images in xcasset

Comment: Set proper constraint

Comment: Add constraints to your view.

Comment: There are two ways:

a) If you use a launch screen.

You are missing a LaunchScreen.storyboard file. Create a LaunchScreen.storyboard file and add it to your project.

b) If you don't use a launch screen.

Go to your Target's settings and choose General, then App Icons and Launch Images. Now set "Launch Screen File" to your "main.storyboard" (or another storyboard if appropriate)

Comment: Thanks Rajat. Thanks Nilesh and Rikh. Your answers solved my question. Thanks a lot again.